# Vue warn data() should return an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, return

Anyone has idea of this error or can see if anything wrong with my syntax that is causing this warning?

**TheResources** is the parent and **StoredResources.vue** & **LearningResource.vue** are childs.

```
data() should return an object. at <LearningResource key="official-guide" id="official-guide" title="Official Guide"  ... > 
  at <StoredResources> 
  at <KeepAlive> 
  at <TheResources> 
  at <App>
```

**TheResources.vue**

```
<template>
    <keep-alive>
            <component :is="selectedTab"></component>
    </keep-alive>
</template>

data() {
        return {
            selectedTab: 'stored-resources',
            storedResources: [
                {
                    id: 'official-guide',
                    title: 'Official Guide',
                    description: 'The official Vue.js documentation.',
                    link: 'https://vuejs.org'
                },
                {
                    id: 'google',
                    title: 'Google',
                    description: 'Learn to Google...',
                    link: 'https://google.org'
                }
            ],
        };
    },
```

**StoredResources.vue**

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <learning-resource
            v-for="res in resources" 
            :key="res.id" 
            :id="res.id"
            :title="res.title"
            :description="res.description"
            :link="res.link"
        ></learning-resource>
    </ul>
</template>
```

**LearningResource.vue**

```
<template>
    <li>
        <base-card>
            <header>
                <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
                <base-button mode="flat" @click="removeResource(id)">Delete</base-button>
            </header>
            <p>{{ description }}</p>
            <nav>
                <a :href="link">View Resource</a>
            </nav>
        </base-card>
    </li>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: [
        'id',
        'title',
        'description',
        'link'
    ],
    inject: ['removeResource'],
    data() {
        
    },
}
</script>
```

Couldn't figure out where went wrong. So help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that this warning is for this component? Because you return an object from `data()` and it seems that there is not any problem. Try re-compiling your code and clearing the cache.

Comment: Oh sorry let me update my thread

Comment: Can you add the code for `LearningResource`? Looks like the issue lies there

Comment: Alright I added that

Comment: In `LearningResource.vue` the `data` property returns nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is written [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#data-properties) that

> The data option for a component is a function. Vue calls this function
> as part of creating a new component instance. It should return an
> object, which Vue will then wrap in its reactivity system and store on
> the component instance as $data

So, try this in `LearningResource.vue`

```
data() {
   return {};        
},
```